# Can not understand why i am getting a Undefined index error

Tags: php, apache, web

Hi i am getting an error  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST on this line can any of you tell me where i am going wrong

```
define("SCH_WSLINK", "{$httpS}://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}");
```

cheers

Comment: I see too many questions like this. Take the time to learn how to [interpret errors and fix your code](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/05/fixing-php-errors/).

Comment: HTTP_HOST may not always be set

Comment: Are you running from the command-line?

Comment: `echo php_sapi_name()` ?

Answer (score 0):

is $httpS defined?

```
$httpS = 'https';
define("SCH_WSLINK", "{$httpS}://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}");
```

The above code works for me...

```
var_dump(SCH_WSLINK);
string(16) "https://test.loc"
```

Comment: This is not really an answer. More of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

the cause of your error is that $httpS is interpreted as a variable which is not defined ,this will work :

```
<?php
    define("SCH_WSLINK", "{\$httpS}://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}");
    echo SCH_WSLINK;
?>
```